# Configuring Lauch configuration using anaconda and KDevelop

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, kdevelop4

How do i configure Kdevelop enviroment on windows to point to my anaconda python installation. I have already set the path on windows. The configure enviroment variable does not have the option to put the path rather it gives the option to enter variable and value.
!https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zcfVGZb8-bKGkw9ww2I4PjBa8yIH9QvG

Comment: Not sure I get it, but can't you just put _variable: PATH, value: <path-to-anaconda-python-bin-dir>_ in there?

Comment: @kfunk. There is no variable:PATH anywhere. There is also no place to set it.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that: You need to insert "PATH" in the column *Variable*, and "<path-to-anaconda-python-bin-dir>" (replace with the correct path) in the *Value* column